# Customize Apex Exception Messages from Javascript Buttons

Tags: apex, javascript, exception

My application has javascript button that call Apex code.  Exceptions from web services are sometimes thrown and the user is shown a detailed exception message like this:

```
A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:
{faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'HttpException: Example Error Message
Class.BananaWebService.fetchBanana: line 22, column 1', }
```

Is there a simple way to create friendly error messages for my users when exceptions are thrown like this:

```
Example Error Message
```

Exception Class

```
public class HttpException extends Exception{}
```

Web Service Class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/BananaWebService/*')
global class BananaWebService {
  webservice static void fetchBanana(Id accountId) {
     throw new HttpException('Example Error Message');
  }
}
```

Javascript code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js")} 

var accountId = "{!Account.Id}";
sforce.apex.execute("BananaWebService","fetchBanana", { accountId: accountId }); 
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your own try-catch block inside your function:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js")} 
try {
var accountId = "{!Account.Id}";
sforce.apex.execute("BananaWebService","fetchBanana", { accountId: accountId }); 
window.location.reload();
} catch(e) { alert("I'm sorry. I can't let you do that, Dave. Here's why: \n\n"+(e.message||e)); }
```

Feel free to customize the error message as you like. You might need to adjust the value for "e", as well.

Comment: Appreciate the help, this is the best solution as it's outside my actual Apex class and my exception class can be used normally in other situations.